# Error circle attribute <cx>: Expected length NaN

Tags: d3.js

I am practicing some d3js charts  and i am getting -

> Error circle attribute cx: Expected length NaN

and

> Error circle attribute cy: Expected length NaN

and . I am assuming it has something to do with data and i have a feeling that my data is wrong. For your reference the link for the code that i am trying is here  - 
http://bl.ocks.org/malcolm-decuire/a98aa2fd81865a6b34a0

Below is my js file

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
      <script>
            var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
                width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            /* 
             * value accessor - returns the value to encode for a given data object.
             * scale - maps value to a visual display encoding, such as a pixel position.
             * map function - maps from data value to display value
             * axis - sets up axis
             */ 

            // setup x 
            var xValue = function(d) { return d.Contributions;}, // data -> value
                xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]), // value -> display
                xMap = function(d) { return xScale(xValue(d));}, // data -> display
                xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom");

            // setup y
            var yValue = function(d) { return d.Deaths;}, // data -> value
                yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]), // value -> display
                yMap = function(d) { return yScale(yValue(d));}, // data -> display
                yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");

            // setup fill color
            var cValue = function(d) { return d.State;},
                color = d3.scale.category10();

            // add the graph canvas to the body of the webpage
            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
              .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            // add the tooltip area to the webpage
            var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
                .attr("class", "tooltip")
                .style("opacity", 0);

            // load data
            d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {

              // change string (from CSV) into number format
              data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.Contributions = +d.Contributions;
                d.Deaths = +d.Deaths;
               console.log(d);
              });

              // don't want dots overlapping axis, so add in buffer to data domain
              xScale.domain([d3.min(data, xValue)-1, d3.max(data, xValue)+1]);
              yScale.domain([d3.min(data, yValue)-1, d3.max(data, yValue)+1]);

              // x-axis
              svg.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "x axis")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                  .call(xAxis)
                .append("text")
                  .attr("class", "label")
                  .attr("x", width)
                  .attr("y", -6)
                  .style("text-anchor", "end")
                  .text("Conntributions");

              // y-axis
              svg.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "y axis")
                  .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                  .attr("class", "label")
                  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                  .attr("y", 6)
                  .attr("dy", ".71em")
                  .style("text-anchor", "end")
                  .text("Deaths");

              // draw dots
              svg.selectAll(".dot")
                  .data(data)
                .enter().append("circle")
                  .attr("class", "dot")
                  .attr("r", 3.5)
                  .attr("cx", xMap)
                  .attr("cy", yMap)
                  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(cValue(d));}) 
                  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                      tooltip.transition()
                           .duration(200)
                           .style("opacity", .9);
                      tooltip.html(d["State"] + "<br/> (" + xValue(d) 
                        + ", " + yValue(d) + ")")
                           .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
                           .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
                  })
                  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                      tooltip.transition()
                           .duration(500)
                           .style("opacity", 0);
                  });

              // draw legend
              var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
                  .data(color.domain())
                .enter().append("g")
                  .attr("class", "legend")
                  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                    return "translate("+ (i * 20 + 137) + ", 6)";
                  });

              // draw legend colored rectangles
              var boxSize = 17;
              legend.append("rect")
                  .attr("x", 0)
                  .attr("width", boxSize)
                  .attr("height", boxSize)
                  .style("fill", color);

              // draw legend text
              legend.append("text")
                  .attr("x", -8.2)
                  .attr("y", 19)
                  .attr("dy", ".35em")
                  .style("text-anchor", "end")
                  .attr("transform","rotate(-43)")
                  .text(function(d) { return d;})
            });

            </script>
```

data.csv

```
  State   Contributions   Deaths
Alaska  0       2.24
Arizona 2,772   3.53
California      17,000  3.25
Colorado        100     1.51
Delaware        100     3.09
Georgia 3,750   3.93
Hawaii  5,250   0.07
Illinois        18,000  1.14
Indiana 3,050   3.29
Iowa    14,753  0.71
Kansas  8,650   2.78
Louisiana       2,796   10.16
Maine   5,000   0.9
Michigan        800     5.06
Minnesota       500     0.82
Mississippi     12,500  7.46
Missouri        7,350   4.64
Montana 2,534   0.76
Nevada  15,500  3.07
New Mexico      4,500   2.98
New York        18,000  4.12
North Carolina  3,750   3.87
North Dakota    7,500   0.93
Ohio    3,600   3.54
Oklahoma        500     3.64
Oregon  11,250  1.05
Pennsylvania    21,812  3.97
Rhode Island    13,875  0.57
South Carolina  500     5.41
South Dakota    2,500   0.68
Tennessee       41,596  3.92
Texas   42,250  2.91
Utah    10,000  0.97
Vermont 3,500   0.75
Virginia        11,500  2.58
Washington      68,300  1.25
West Virginia   1,500   2.87
Wisconsin       21,325  1.47
```

Comment: You don't have a CSV. And that's not a valid TSV either.

Comment: I have added a CSV in my question. Isn't that a valid CSV ?

Comment: No. CSV means "**comma** separated values".

Comment: I edited csv file again. May i know how do u check whether or not this is a valid csv or tsv file ?

Comment: That's not a CSV. Again, CSV is "comma separated values". You can search online what is a CSV, there are plenty of resources.

Comment: Okay that was quiet helpful. As a workaround what i did was i manually typed data in excel spreadsheet and then i converted that .xlsx file into .csv and now i am able to visualize data

Comment: Don't forget to remove those commas in the numbers (thousands separator).

Comment: Yes i did remove those. Thanks

Comment: @Jon: maybe a nice exercise is to port your code to D3v5 instead of sticking to a version that will never get modified. It is not that difficult.

Comment: @rioV8: Im new to the v5 version. What is different in the v5 version in this case?

Comment: @3TW3: Mainly the axis and scales, look them up on the d3 website